# How to disable CAS cache with app.config?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0, app-config, cas

I ran into issue when my .net application takes too long to "cold run" (means when starting it first time after PC boot).

I saw with procmon a lot of reading and writing files with .cch extension, that i understand as CAS cache.

I'm suspecting this making the performance problem, and i want to disable the use of CAS cache, to let the .net framework process the security over and over every startup of my application without reading and writing CAS cache.

How to do that? preferably with app.config

Thanks.

Comment: That would make it *slower*.  The point of the .cch files is to avoid having to parse the xml files.

Comment: I prefer to do more parsing instead of reading and writing files, because Hard Disk Drive is my bottleneck right now and makes the whole cold startup to be very very slow.

Comment: It will read the .xml files instead of the .cch files.  Of course that doesn't make it faster.